# How to access correct width value from IB with Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, interface-builder

I have some strange Issues.

I have a `UIViewController` and only 1 `UIView` (I call it containerView) inside. The `UIView` should have the same Width as the `UIViewController`.

So I set the Leading and the Trailing Constraints between the `UIView` and the `UIViewController` to 0. During runtime everything works fine, BUT, how can I access the actual width during runtime? I tried it with:

```
self.containerView.frame.size.width
```

but of course frames doesn't work with `autolayout` and I only got a width of 600.0f, which is the standard width from the Interface Builder!

I also tried to set a fixed Constraint Width but this also makes no sense because the `iPhone` has a different Screen Width as the `iPad` for example.

Any Ideas how i can access the Width of my `UIVIew` during runtime.

PS: As you can see i use `Interface Builder`, `Size Classes` and `Autolayout`!

Comment: Are you examining the width in `viewDidLoad`? If so, the view hasn't been laid out yet and the width will read 600. Check the width in `viewDidAppear` and it should read the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to get the width in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews 
 { 
    NSLog(@"%f", self.containerView.frame.size.width);
 }
```

and since your `UIView` have 0 space to all screen edges the width of the `UIView` will be the same as the screen size so you can get it like this:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
```

Comment: @Davis glad  it helps, please consider accepting the answer if it works